# Folder-by-feature VS2015 Ionic Template

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

The project generated by `Visual Studio 2015 > Apache Cordova Apps > Ionic JavaScript`folder structure is not grouped by feature, but instead by type.

It's something like this

`www
--css
----page1.scss
----page2.scss
--js
----page1.controller.js
----page2.controller.js
--templates
----page1.html
----page2.html`

I want it to be like this

`www
--pages
----page1
------page1.controller.js
------page1.html
------page1.scss
----page2
------page2.controller.js
------page2.html
------page2.scss`

I'm fairly new to Angular and changing the routes will be a real challenge.

I'm just wondering there is an existing VS2015 Ionic project with folder-by-feature. Or any tips on my journey on changing the project.

I already have a running Ionic but I cannot debug it on my Windows Phone using `VS2015 > New > Project From Existing COde` then Debug on Windows phone. The project is forked from here: https://github.com/MaximAbramchuck/ionic-gulp-es6-starter-kit.

I also cannot do `ionic emulate windows`.

Comment: What error did you get,when compiling this project?

Comment: There were quite a lot because I kept testing different boilerplates. I run the app on my phone using Visual Studio. Some of the error I get is to install a certificate thing. And the other error is that the structure of the project was not converted properly to a VS2015 project because it needs a `www` folder for the codes. Simply changing `src` to `www` doesn't seem to work. Right now I just used the Ionic 2 (Beta 10) Templates. Ionic 2, Angular 2 and Typescript. Challenging but it has the correct structure.

Comment: You need to follow the install process of this project sites and use `gulp` to  compile from sources. I tried that, after fixing all the errors, this project seems to inject contents dynamically, which will be prevented by windows platform(`Unable to add dynamic content` Exception was thrown). Please see[Developing secure apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh849625.aspx). So I don't think it is a project designed for windows platform.